# How to prevent VideoDetector plugin for Ckeditor to duplicate content when there are multiple instances on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

**The setup and goal:**

I am using the Video Detector plugin for CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/addon/videodetector

My goal is to allow for videos to be added to the content.

There are about five instances of CKeditor on the page. Each has .ckeditor class to initialise the plugin (the jQuery plugin is included). Then in the code I set up the custom toolbar that is used by default for all the plugins on the page.

You can see below the example setup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
        [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord' ],
        {
            name: 'basicstyles',
            groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ],
            items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ]
        },
        {
            name: 'paragraph',
            groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ],
            items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ]
        },
        {
            name: 'links',
            items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'VideoDetector' ]
        }
    ];

    CKEDITOR.config.uiColor = '#e5e5e5';
    CKEDITOR.config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
    CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'videodetector';
    CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'iframe[*]';
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
});
```

**The problem:**

This configuration works, but the problems start when you begin inserting the videos in the different instances. To begin with, if you add a **different** videos to each CKEditor instance using the plugin, the **same** video is always added. I can only insert new videos if I save, refresh and then insert the new videos. However, once I save the form the initial video is replaced by the new ones.

I think the problem is potentially to do with the instances and them overwriting each other, but I am not sure how to solve it.

Let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but in my case I was just trying to insert multiple videos into the same editor. The issue is that the plugin is looking for the first element with a class of cke_dialog_contents. Every time.

I modified the plugin code so that the value from the dialog input element is retrieved in the dialog onOK function and then passed to the parsing function, rather than asking the parsing function to find the value from the DOM. I have not tried this with multiple instances of the editor on a page as in your example, but I suspect it should work equally well in that scenario.

First, alter the onOK function to retrieve the value from its own dialog:

```
onOk: function(){
    var dialog = this;
    var inputVal = dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'url_video');
    //detectamos el video
    var respuesta = detectar(inputVal);
```

Then alter the dectectar() function to accept the string as an argument:

```
function detectar(inputVal){
    var url = inputVal;
```

I am using ckeditor 4.3.4 and videodetector 1.1.

Comment: Thanks, I need to check as this was a while back, but I found a workaround myself.